# dpkg outputs "Version" meaning

Tags: debian-wheezy

I'm either not very good at searching or not very good (in general).

What's the meaning of "Version" here?  The version of GCC used to build the package?

```
# dpkg -s linux-image-3.2.0-4-amd64|grep Version
Version: 3.2.96-2
```

Answer (score 1):

It's the version of the package that is current installed.

Comment: That makes sense, but then what is "3.2.0-4"?

Comment: Questions go in questions, not comments.